# Law of a step function and its generalization to two dimensions on an appropriate spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let's consider two discontinuous functions defined on $D$ and $D \times [0,T]$, respectively:

- A step function: $u_1(x)=\begin{cases}
   u_{L}, x<c_1, \\[2ex]
   u_{R}, x>c_1,
   \end{cases}$
- A "generalization to two dimensions": $u_2(x,t)=\begin{cases}
   u_{L}, x<c_2\cdot t, \\[2ex]
   u_{R}, x>c_2\cdot t.
   \end{cases}$

Here $x \in D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $t \in [0,T]$ and $c_1,c_2,u_{L},u_{R}$ are constants. Additionaly in the book "Stochastic equations in infinite dimensions, Da Prato G., Zabczyk J., 1992", we could find the definition of the *law*:

If $X$ is a random variable from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ to $(E,\mathcal{S})$ and $P$ a probability measure on $\Omega$, then by $\mathcal{L}(X)$ we will denote the image of $P$ under the mapping $X$: $\mathcal{L}(X)(A)=P\{\omega \in \Omega:x(\omega)\in A\},\forall A\in \mathcal{S}.$ The measure $ \mathcal{L} (X)$ is called the *distribution* or the *law* of $X$.

**As far as I know the probability law of $u_1$ and $u_2$ is the Dirac mass at $u_1$ and $u_2$, respectively, seen as a measure on an appropriate function space.** Although I can't remember where I have read this in the literature. If my recollection is wrong, please correct me.

If we assume that the last paragraph above is correct, my question is: **What would be those appropriate spaces in the cases of the functions $u_1$ and $u_2$?**

Example I got last week for the $u_1$: the law of the function $u_1$ is the Dirac measure concentrated at $u_1$ on the space of cadlag function from [0,1] to $\mathbb{R}$. But for the problem I have in my mind cadlag functions probably won't work.

For the function $u_2$ I don't have any examples. I think that the space of $BV$ functions from $(D\times [0,T])$ to $\mathbb{R}$ should be one of the appropriate spaces. But my ideal appropriate spaces should look as $C([0,T];\mathcal{M}(D))$ or  similar - they should be Banach space-valued.

I work on one problem for a few weeks that concerns these two functions and in order to apply the technique that was recommended me (in order to solve it), I need to consider the laws of this two functions. I need help with this. Any appropriate space you recommend me is welcome. Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions $u_1$ and $u_2$ are not completely defined. For instance, $u_1(c_1)$ is undefined.

If you do not need to distinguish functions differing only on a set of Lebesgue measure $0$, then you may consider $u_1$ a point in the Banach space $B_1:=L^\infty(D)$, and $u_2$ a point in the Banach space $B_2:=L^\infty(D\times[0,T])$, where $D$ is any nonempty Lebesgue-measurable subset of $\mathbb R$.

For $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$, you can take any probability space. For each $i\in\{1,2\}$, you can take any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal S_i$ over $B_i$, and then the probability law of the (nonrandom) random element $\Omega\ni\omega\mapsto u_i\in B_i$ will be the [Dirac measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure) on $B_i$ at $u_i$.

---

**Added in response to a comment by the OP:** Of course, you can identify any function $w\colon X\times Y\to Z$ with the function $\tilde w\colon Y\to Z^X$ by the formula $\tilde w(y)(x):=w(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in X\times Y$.

In the case of your function $u_2\colon D\times[0,T]\to\mathbb R$, the corresponding function $\tilde u_2$ may be considered as follows: 
$$[0,T]\ni t\mapsto\tilde u_2\in \tilde B_2:=L^\infty\big([0,T],L^\infty(\mathbb R)\big),$$
where $D\ni x\mapsto\tilde u_2(t):=u_2(x,t)\in\mathbb R$. Then the probability law of the (nonrandom) random element $\Omega\ni\omega\mapsto\tilde u_2\in\tilde B_2$ will be the Dirac measure on the Banach space $\tilde B_2$ at the point $\tilde u_2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For my problem it doesn't important what $u_1(c_1)$, $u_2(c_2 \cdot t, t)$ is. You could take $u_R$ for both of them. My guesses for $u_1$ would be $L^{\infty}(D)$ too, but also $BV(D)$ - space of functions with bounded variation, $\mathcal{M}(D)$ - space of Radon measures and $\mathcal{D}^{'}(D)$ - space of distributions. I am not sure if I am right. For the function $u_2$ the space  $L^{\infty}(D \times [0,T])$ sounds good. I guess also that the spaces $BV(D \times[0,T])$, $\mathcal{M}(D \times [0,T])$,  $\mathcal{D}^{'}(D \times [0,T])$ could work too?

Comment: @Mark : Yes, you can use many other spaces instead of $L^\infty$. However, for $BV$ and $\mathcal D'$, you need to assume that $D$ is open and also replace $[0,T]$ by $(0,T)$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction on $BV$ and $\mathcal{D}^{'}$. For  $u_1$  spaces such as $\mathcal{M}$ and $L^p, p\in[0,\infty]$ sounds good for application. However I am not sure for the $u_2$. For it I need some Banach space-valued spaces. Last year I asked question on MSE for the function $u_2$ (edited today) (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254479/a-function-of-time-and-space-as-a-collection-of-functions-of-space-that-is-param). There is a big list there at the end of it. I think that at least some of those Banach space-valued spaces could work. Am I wrong? And thanks again.

Comment: @Mark : I have added a response to your latest comment.

Comment: @Mark, $\mathcal D^{'}$ `$\mathcal D^{'}$` (as in [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354516/law-of-a-step-function-and-its-generalization-to-two-dimensions-on-an-appropriat#comment889502_354547) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354516/law-of-a-step-function-and-its-generalization-to-two-dimensions-on-an-appropriat#comment889505_354547)) sets the prime too high.  You want $\mathcal D'$ `$\mathcal D'$` (as in [3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354516/law-of-a-step-function-and-its-generalization-to-two-dimensions-on-an-appropriat#comment889503_354547)).

Comment: @LSpice, thanks for the correction.  It is one of those things I didn't learn correctly from the start, and now I make that mistake from time to time.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, thank you for your detailed answer. I don't know if I will end up using your space $\tilde B_2$. But that is  great example. It was recommended me to use space such as $\tilde B_2:=C([0,T];G)$ with appropriate $G$ and with appropriate convergence. On bounded domains $L^{\infty} \subset L^1 \subset \mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal D '$. So I thinkI will use space $\tilde{B}_2:=C([0,T];\mathcal{M})$ i.e. $G=\mathcal{M}$  and of course with weak convergence of measures (i.e. $C_{w}([0,T];\mathcal{M})$ on that big list in my MSE question). Hope that I am not mistaken. Thanks again.